# Where is the action method "setElementClass" defined?

Tags: xml, magento

I have searched the entire magento folder for the text "setElementClass" and it only appears in xml files as a call to the action method named setElementClass.  I expected it to be defined in a php class somewhere, but it is nowhere to be found.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `Varien_Object::__call()` from which all blocks in Magento extend. Any method beginning in get set has or uns is "ok".

Comment: Thanks.  So, it doesn't do what I thought it did, but now I know I can stop going down that particular rabbit hole.